# JPA 2.0 Eclipselink - Adding/Deleting to child list gets optimistic lock

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

I am having an issue where eclipselink (2.5) is throwing an OptimisticLockException even though the only thing I'm modifiying is trying to either add or remove an item from a child list.

Entities :

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="PLAN_ORG_RELATIONSHIP")
    @Customizer(GridCacheCustomizer.class)
    @AdditionalCriteria("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN this.startDate AND this.endDate")
    @NamedQuery(name="PlanOrganizationRelationship.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PlanOrganizationRelationship p")
    @Portable
    public class PlanOrganizationRelationship extends PrismObject implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="planOrganizationRelationship", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,    orphanRemoval=true) 
    @PortableProperty(10)
    private List<PlanOrganizationAction> planOrganizationActions;

public PlanOrganizationAction addPlanOrganizationAction(PlanOrganizationAction planOrganizationAction) {
        getPlanOrganizationActions().add(planOrganizationAction);
        planOrganizationAction.setPlanOrgRelationship(this);
        return planOrganizationAction;
    }

    public PlanOrganizationAction removePlanOrganizationAction(PlanOrganizationAction planOrganizationAction) {
        getPlanOrganizationActions().remove(planOrganizationAction);
        planOrganizationAction.setPlanOrgRelationship(null);
        return planOrganizationAction;
    }

    @Column(name="LST_UPDT_DT")
    @Version
    @PortableProperty(5)
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedDate;
}
```

Other side of One To Many:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PLAN_ORGANIZATION_ACTION")
@Customizer(GridCacheCustomizer.class)
@AdditionalCriteria("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN this.startDate AND this.endDate")
@NamedQuery(name="PlanOrganizationAction.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM PlanOrganizationAction p")
@Portable
public class PlanOrganizationAction extends PrismObject implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PLN_ORG_RLTNP_SEQ_ID")
    @PortableProperty(7)
    private PlanOrganizationRelationship planOrganizationRelationship;
}
```

I have 3 paths - Adding new Relationship with Actions (both entities new) or Add an Action or Remove Action

When I am adding both, I perist the parent and the children are persisted as well and that is the expected behavior.
When I try to add or remove I try something like

```
PrismOrganizationRelationship por = findById (..) //we are spring-data-jpa
por.addPlanOrganizationAction(action);
repo.save(por); // Throws optimistic lock - even though @Version is the same
```

Not sure what is causing this issue ?

Comment: Can you turn EclipseLink logging on and show the SQL logged for the transaction, specifically the statement resulting in the exception?  James describes what should occur here http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg04356.html but mentions that the behavior is configurable - check that your customizers are not changing the locks behavior to cascade.

Comment: I have logging set to fine, but it doesn't actually log the sql for the insert because it throws the OptimisticLockException first

Comment: You dont show how the find or save methods work, so if they are using different contexts, the por instance might be stale which would cause an optistic lock exception on merge in a new context.  Try checking what the save method does, and the state of the object before the call and after (but before the exception).  You might also try an em.refresh() to see if the state is different.  Does the exception give any other information?  Could the exception be caused by the change in the child object?

Answer (score 0):

Check `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`. It work only for persist(save newly entity) operation. your operation **remove child entity** mean updating main entity. That`s why, you need to use`CascadeType.MARGE` for update operation.